# How can I access variables within a database?

Tags: php, mysql

An application I'm working on requires that I store certain values in a database (coming from a submitted form). Like for example:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Employment (JobTitle, StartDate, EndDate) VALUES('$_POST[jobtitle]','$_POST[startdate]','$_POST[enddate]')";
```

Once they're in the database, how do I access them individually in the following context:

```
 if ($jobtitle=='123') {
        echo "You're a software developer.";
    } elseif ($jobtitle=='1234') {
        echo "You're a software tester.";
    }
```

Essentially, it's a recommender system where I need to be able to issue recommendations based off of the data in the database. I.e., if job title is this, if start date - end date = this, etc. I'm a beginner with mySQL. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to perform a `SELECT` query to retrieve a subset of the data from the database.  I suggest reading the [MySQL tutorial](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tutorial.html), in particular the section on [retrieving information](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/retrieving-data.html).

Comment: If you compose your SQL queries like in the example, that application you are working on can be owned by an attacker in a couple of minutes due to SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) First, you need to know at least a little PHP.  It sounds like you've gotten that far, and that you can successfully establish a connection to the database (at least to do your "insert").  Good.

2) Next, you need to know at least a little SQL.  It sounds like that's where you're stumped at the moment.  The most basic SQL commands are:

- Select (usually people learn this one first ;))
- Insert
- Update
- Delete

  W3Schools has a series of great on-line tutorials that cover 1) and 2):

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp

3) Before you put anything into production, you should ALSO learn a bit about security:

- Securing your web server (e.g. Apache)

  http://bignosebird.com/security.shtml
- Securing your database (e.g. mySQL)

  http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/securing-mysql-step-step
- Securing your application (e.g. against cross-site scripting and SQL injection)

  http://www.insanevisions.com/article/221/Tutorials/PHP-Security/

Comment: I understand how to construct a SELECT statement to pull the contents of the table. What I don't know how to do is structure the results of that select statement for use by a recommender system.

Comment: Please clarify your question: 1) update your post: show us your "select" code, 2) please tell us what you don't understand about this code.  Also: please take a glance at tutorials cited.  They might help with this question; they'll certainly help with your project.

Comment: @paulsm4 is right - you are basically asking a question which says "I don't understand how to use PHP and MySQL in conjunction. Somebody teach me." It is ok to ask questions early on but take the time to learn the basics before asking and it will go a long way.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_select_db("user", $con);
$sql="SELECT jobtitle FROM employment";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['jobtitle'];    
}
```